# Detect space between text (OpenCV, Python)

Tags: python, opencv, handwriting-recognition

I have the following code (which is in fact just 1 part of 4 needed to run all the project I am working on..):

```
#python classify.py --model models/svm.cpickle --image images/image.png

from __future__ import print_function
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from hog import HOG
import dataset
import argparse
import mahotas
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required = True,
    help = "path to where the model will be stored")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True,
    help = "path to the image file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

model = joblib.load(args["model"])

hog = HOG(orientations = 18, pixelsPerCell = (10, 10),
    cellsPerBlock = (1, 1), transform = True)

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 30, 150)
(_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cnts = sorted([(c, cv2.boundingRect(c)[0]) for c in cnts], key =
    lambda x: x[1])

for (c, _) in cnts:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    if w >= 7 and h >= 20:
        roi = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        thresh = roi.copy()
        T = mahotas.thresholding.otsu(roi)
        thresh[thresh > T] = 255
        thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)

        thresh = dataset.deskew(thresh, 20)
        thresh = dataset.center_extent(thresh, (20, 20))

        cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)

        hist = hog.describe(thresh)
        digit = model.predict([hist])[0]
        print("I think that number is: {}".format(digit))

        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h),
        (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.putText(image, str(digit), (x - 10, y - 10),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.2, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("image", image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This code is detecting and recognizing handwriten digits from images. Here is an example:

[image]

Let's say I don't care about the accuracy recognition.

My problem is the following: as you can see, the program take all the numbers he can *see* and print them in console. From console I can save them in a text file if I want BUT I can't tell the program that there is a space between the numbers.

[image: Image2]

What I want is that, if I print the numbers in a text file, they should be separated as in the image (sorry but it's a bit hard to explain..).
The numbers should not be (even in console) printed all together but, where there is blank space, printed a blank area also.

Take a look at the firs image. After the first 10 digits, there is a blank space in image which there isn't in console.

Anyway, here is a link to full code. There are 4 `.py` files and 3 folders. To execute, open a CMD in the folder and paste the command `python classify.py --model models/svm.cpickle --image images/image.png` where `image.png` is the name of one file in images folder.

[Full Code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7zqe2yJoD0sQlFUbWZReFNBQ0E)

Thanks in advance. In my opinion all this work would have to be done using neural networks but I want to try it first this way. I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: hi i want to calculate the distance between digits in an image? can you give me ideas how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used this code to do the job. It detects region of text/digits in images.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Bob\\Desktop\\PyHw\\images\\test5.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # grayscale
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) # threshold
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel,iterations = 13) # dilate
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) # get contours


idx =0
# for each contour found, draw a rectangle around it on original image
for contour in contours:

    idx += 1

    # get rectangle bounding contour
    [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

    # discard areas that are too large
    if h>300 and w>300:
        continue

    # discard areas that are too small
    if h<40 or w<40:
        continue

    # draw rectangle around contour on original image
    #cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,255),2)

    roi = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    cv2.imwrite('C:\\Users\\Bob\\Desktop\\' + str(idx) + '.jpg', roi)

    cv2.imshow('img',roi)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The code is based on this other question/answer: [Extracting text OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506105/extracting-text-opencv)

Answer (score 1):

This is a starter solution.

I don't have anything in Python for the time being but it shouldn't be hard to convert this plus the OpenCV function calls are similar and I've linked them below.

---

**TLDR;**

Find the centre of your boundingRects, then find the distance between them. If one rect is a certain threshold away, you may *assume* it as being a space.

---

First, find the centres of your bounding rectangles

```
vector<Point2f> centres;

for(size_t index = 0; index < contours.size(); ++index)
{
    Moments moment = moments(contours[index]);

    centres.push_back(Point2f(static_cast<float>(moment.m10/moment.m00), static_cast<float>(moment.m01/moment.m00)));
}
```

*(Optional but recommended)*

You can draw the centres to have a visual understanding of them.

```
for(size_t index = 0; index < centres.size(); ++index)
{
    Scalar colour = Scalar(255, 255, 0);
    circle(frame, circles[index], 2, colour, 2);
}
```

With this, just iterate through them confirming that the distance to the next one is within a *reasonable* threshold

```
for(size_t index = 0; index < centres.size(); ++index)
{
    // this is just a sample value. Tweak it around to see which value actually makes sense
    double distance = 0.5;
    Point2f current = centres[index];
    Point2f nextPoint = centres[index + 1];

    // norm calculates the euclidean distance between two points
    if(norm(nextPoint - current) >= distance)
    {
        // TODO: This is a potential space??
    }
}
```

You can read more about [moments](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html), [norm](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#double%20norm(InputArray%20src1,%20int%20normType,%20InputArray%20mask)) and [circle drawing](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html) calls in Python.

Happy coding,
Cheers mate :)